# Handling iOS Safari Address Bar Overlap in a TailwindCSS Web App

Tags: html, css, ios

I'm developing a web app for iOS using TailwindCSS, and I'm encountering a layout issue when the app is run in Safari. My design includes a navigation bar with h-screen and overflow-y-scroll. However, on iOS, Safari's address bar overlaps the content, causing the bottom part of my navigation bar to be obscured.

This seems to be due to the dynamic nature of the Safari address bar, which changes in size as the user scrolls, altering the visible viewport height. As a result, the lower part of my web app is hidden behind the iOS interface, and I can't seem to find a way to adjust my layout to accommodate this.

I've tried using 100vh for height, but it doesn't account for the address bar's variability. I'm looking for a CSS-based solution, preferably one that integrates smoothly with TailwindCSS.

Is there a standard or recommended way to handle this issue? Specifically, I'm looking for a solution that:

Adjusts the height of my navigation bar to ensure it's fully visible regardless of the address bar's size.
Integrates with TailwindCSS without requiring extensive overrides or custom styles.
Is responsive and maintains the usability of the navigation bar across different iOS devices.
Any suggestions or insights from those who have tackled similar issues in iOS Safari would be greatly appreciated.

Here is a sample setup to reproduce the issue. If you make the Content text long enough the logout button is covered by the navigation bar:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Navbar Issue</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="h-screen flex flex-col justify-between w-40 bg-gray-100 fixed">
      <div>
        <h2 class="font-bold my-4 text-center">Navigation</h2>
        <ul class="my-2">
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="inline-block bg-gray-200 text-center w-full p-2">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="inline-block bg-gray-200 text-center w-full p-2">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="inline-block bg-gray-200 text-center w-full p-2">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="inline-block bg-gray-200 text-center w-full p-2">Link</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div>
        <a href="#" class="inline-block bg-gray-200 text-center w-full p-2">Logout</a>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <main class="pl-44 py-4 w-full">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```